# MS Access combo box

Tags: forms, ms-access, autofill

I'm new to forms in MS access and I've created a form with a combo box that auto fills a few things i'm looking for, basically and name, phone #, and check out date. I have added another text box for "check in date" and I'm able to input the date but it will update the first record in the table that I'm pulling information from and not the record that the auto fill combo box displays. would anyone know a fix to update the record that the auto fill display versus the top record of the table?

```
Private Sub Combo0_Change()

Me.txtfname = Me.Combo0.Column(1)
Me.txtlname = Me.Combo0.Column(2)
Me.txtphone = Me.Combo0.Column(3)
Me.txtpump = Me.Combo0.Column(4)
Me.txtdateissue = Me.Combo0.Column(5)
Me.txtduedate = Me.Combo0.Column(6)
Me.txtCheckInDate = Me.Combo0.Column(7)

End Sub




Private Sub Combo0_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub txtCheckInDate_Change()

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your combo box is just filling in the record you currently have open (i.e. the first record.)   That's why only the top record is updating.   You need to first have you trigger go to the record you want to update (research docmd.findrecord) and then update your current record.  I'm assuming your form is bound to the table you are updating?

Other option is to change the recordsource of your form

Comment: yep, it's bound to the table

Answer (score 0):

get the source of `Combo0` combobox, then in `Private Sub txtCheckInDate_Change()` function, change its source to that source + your filter, like

```
 Me.Combo0.RowSource = "[Existing Combo Source SQL]" & _
 " WHERE [YourDateField] = #" & me.txtCheckInDate & "#"
```

Comment: I hate to sound like a noob, but I'm very new to access, when you say source of combo0, what do you mean?

Comment: `RowSource` from properties